# Counting classes up with each

Tags: jquery, count, each

I am trying to give each .scan a new class but with increasing count

What i have tried was using the each function from jQuery and then using $(this) but $(this) will allways contain only the class name so every .scan will be changed.

```
$( ".scan" ).each(function() {
    i = 0;
    $(this).addClass( "count"+i );
    i++;
});
```

The Result was

```
<div class="scan count0"></div>
<div class="scan count0"></div>
```

But what i want is

```
<div class="scan count0"></div>
<div class="scan count1"></div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/regk7aay/1/) with my current state.

Every tipp/help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i.e. because i is defined inside each method.You need to set i value outside each method:

```
var i = 0;
$( ".scan" ).each(function() {
   $(this).addClass( "count"+i );
  i++;
});
```

However you can use default argument parameter index of each function to give incremenetal class suffix:

```
$(".scan").each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass("count" + i);
});
```

**[Working Demo with .each](https://jsfiddle.net/c7yuckkh/)**

or use callback function of `addClass()` method:

```
$(".scan").addClass(function(i){
  return "count" + i;
});
```

**[Working Demo with .addClass](https://jsfiddle.net/t6r2yq1x/)**